# Gitlab's CI docker in docker login and test containers

Tags: docker, gradle, gitlab-ci, java-14, docker-in-docker

I have a project that needs a TestContainers running to execute end2end tests.
The Containers 's image is another project which docker image is pushed to GitLab's Container Registry. This means that, whenever I want to do docker pull of this image, I need to do a docker login first.

Locally it works fine, I just do a login, run my tests and everything's ok.. on the pipeline is another story.

In [GitLab's documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#using-docker-caching), on the pipeline's configuration file `.gitlab-ci.yml`, they use `image: docker:19.03.12`. The problem with that is that I need to run `./gradlew`, and said image doesn't have java for it to run. Otherwise, if I set the image to `image: gradle:jdk14`, even if I setup DockerInDocker, when I run `docker login`, it says docker is not recognized as a command.

I tried creating a custom image with Docker and Java14, but still get the following error:

```
com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.NotFoundException: {"message":"pull access denied for registry.gitlab.com/projects/projecta, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied"}
```

As you can see in the gitlab-ci file, it's running docker login before executing the tests, and according to the pipeline's output is successful

`.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
image: gradle:jdk14

variables:
  GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false"

stages:
  - build
  - test

before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle

assemble:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew assemble
  only:
    changes:
      - "**/*.gradle.kts"
      - gradle.properties
  cache:
    key: $CI_PROJECT_NAME
    paths:
      - .gradle/wrapper
      - .gradle/caches
    policy: push

cache:
  key: $CI_PROJECT_NAME
  paths:
    - .gradle/wrapper
    - .gradle/caches
  policy: pull

test:
  stage: test
  image: registry.gitlab.com/project/docker-jdk14:latest #<-- my custom image
  dependencies:
    - checkstyle
  services:
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  script:
    - docker login -u $CI_DEPLOY_USER -p $CI_DEPLOY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    - ./gradlew test
```

I have the feeling that I'm missing something but so far the only explanation I can come up with is that the `docker login` the pipeline is executing doesn't set the credentials to the inner docker instance.

Is there anyway to call the login in the inner instance instead of the outer one?

I thought about doing the login call inside the test.. but that would be my last option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly you're trying to run CI for project `gitlab.com/projects/projectb`, which uses image built in project `gitlab.com/projects/projecta` during tests.

You're attempting to pull image `registry.gitlab.com/projects/projecta` using username and password from predefined variables `$CI_DEPLOY_USER` and `$CI_DEPLOY_PASSWORD`.

It doesn't work, because that user has only permissions to access `gitlab.com/projects/projectb`. What you need to do is to create deploy token for project `gitlab.com/projects/projecta` with permissions to access the registry, supply it to your CI in `gitlab.com/projects/projectb` via custom variables and use those to login to `$CI_REGISTRY`.